# IExpress - Disable Compression

Tags: iexpress

Does anybody know if there is a way to configure IExpress (presumably via the SED file) to not compress the files it builds into an installer package?  The reason for this is the files I'm packaging are already compressed (except for setup.exe, which is very small), and the extra compression only adds to the build time without saving any additional space.

I have seen on this [SED Overview](http://www.mdgx.com/INF_web/cdfinfo.htm) that there are some options to control compression type.  I have tried various configurations, but none of them seem to make a difference.  The IExpress build process uses the Microsoft makecab utility, and it doesn't appear to pass the correct parameters to makecab when the SED file specifies NONE for CompressionType.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417343.aspx#set_comp_type) there is a way to disable compression in cabinet files.  I just need to figure out how to tell IExpress to do it.

As an aside, another motivation for disabling this compression is that I've noticed Microsoft Security Essentials seems to take particular interest in IExpress Packages.  It appears to decompress them to scan the contents whenever the file is copied, which can take a significant amount of time on a 100MB package.  I was thinking that the scanning might go quicker if it didn't have to decompress the package first.

Answer (score 4):

I built a `.sed` file with IExpress, then added

```
Compress=0
```

just before the line `InsideCompressed=0`. Seems to work!

Comment: Worked perfectly on Windows 10!